# Checkbox checked on page load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am wondering why my checkbox won't check when I tell it to do so during a page load. Here's what I have:

```
if($('#contentPlaceholder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C010_ctl00_ctl00_checkBoxes_0').is(":checked")==false){
   alert('works');
   $('input:checkbox[value="Sample 1"]').prop("checked", true);
}
```

It gets to the alert but after that it won't check the property.

**EDIT** Here's part of the HTML

```
<input id="contentPlaceholder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C010_ctl00_ctl00_checkBoxes_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$contentPlaceholder$C003$ctl00$ctl00$C010$ctl00$ctl00$checkBoxes$0" value="Sample 1">
```

if I do like a click event using the same selector, it works.

**EDIT2** It works in JSfiddle. I guess it has to do with Sitefinity. I'll have to take a look into it.

Comment: Why don't you just do `<input type="checkbox" id="test" checked="checked">` that will check it initially...

Comment: try with document.ready

Comment: I'm getting `undefined is not a function` when the page loads, so I think your selector inside the if is wrong. checking now.

Comment: Your code [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/kenwqpnr/1/). Do you have the value of the target input set to `"Sample 1"?

Comment: Could you provide your html?

Comment: @Aravind Yes I have that in the beggining of the Js file.  This is just one section of the code that I'm having trouble.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova agreed. I am not sure if the `contentPlaceholder` is the same checkbox as the `Sample 1` checkbox, since two different selectors are being used here.

Comment: What do `console.log($('#contentPlaceholder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C010_ctl00_ctl00_checkBoxes_0'))` and `console.log($('input:checkbox[value="Sample 1"]'))` return?

Comment: Look in the console for the debugger in whichever browser you are using, what errors, if any, are there?

Comment: Also note that I'm working using Sitefinity. It's weird that it works in JSfiddle

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `prop()` was added in version 1.6, so maybe you aren't using a new enough version in your environment?

Comment: @ OpuLance works on `fiddle` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ydfcnfLy/) make sure you have included `jquery`

Comment: Found the problem and it's because of one of the Sitefinity scripts that automatically loads.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input:checkbox[value="Sample 1"]').prop("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```
$('input:checkbox[value="Sample 1"]').attr("checked", true);
```

Comment: This does not work. Using `prop` instead of `attr` works though.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working maybe you don't add jquery library..

i just put a test code to see it

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" value="Sample 1" id="contentPlaceholder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C010_ctl00_ctl00_checkBoxes_0" >test1</input>

<input type="checkbox" value="Sample 2" id="contentPlaceholder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C010_ctl00_ctl00_checkBoxes_0" >test2</input>

<script> 



if($('#contentPlaceholder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C010_ctl00_ctl00_checkBoxes_0').is(":checked")==false){
   alert('works');
   $('input:checkbox[value="Sample 1"]').prop("checked", true);


}

 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP says the alert is shown, hence the jQuery also has to be loaded already.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, as you can see in the snippet below. Just make sure you are including the jQuery 1.6 library at a minimum, because that is when the `prop()` method was added.

https://api.jquery.com/prop/

```js
if ($('#contentPlaceholder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C010_ctl00_ctl00_checkBoxes_0').is(":checked") == false) {
  alert('works');
  $('input:checkbox[value="Sample 1"]').prop("checked", true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="contentPlaceholder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C010_ctl00_ctl00_checkBoxes_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$contentPlaceholder$C003$ctl00$ctl00$C010$ctl00$ctl00$checkBoxes$0" value="Sample 1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a Sitefinity code is running **after** your code and overrides your value.